# Hadoop : JPS can not find Java installed

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, mapreduce

my configurations are

```
hduser@worker1:/usr/local/hadoop/conf$ jps
The program 'jps' can be found in the following packages:
 * openjdk-6-jdk
 * openjdk-7-jdk
Ask your administrator to install one of them
```

I have java installed though

```
hduser@worker1:/usr/local/hadoop/conf$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre10-0ubuntu5)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

hduser@worker1:/usr/local/hadoop/conf$ echo $JAVA_HOME 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk
```

and also set up in `conf/hadoop-env.sh`

```
hduser@worker1:/usr/local/hadoop/conf$ cat hadoop-env.sh | grep JAVA_HOME
# The only required environment variable is JAVA_HOME.  All others are
# set JAVA_HOME in this file, so that it is correctly defined on
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk
```

How can I make JPS work?

Comment: Use Oracle (Sun) Java in place of OpenJDK. OpenJDK is not recommended for Hadoop as per their documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like open-jdk does not have jps in it.
For hadoop, installing sun-jvm would be a better choice.

Answer (score 9):

Saurabh Saxena's answer above is no longer correct.
To get jps, you want to also install the development tools java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel.
On CentOS 6 the file is: 
java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64

So:

```
yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk*
```

will do the trick (also picks up demo and javadocs besides the jdk and dev tools, but you will get the full complement of command line tools).

For Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel
```

For all these examples, you can try JDK7 (just substitute 1.7), and as of December 2012, Hadoop is pretty stable without the Oracle libraries. See: http://openjdk.java.net/install/

Comment: I ran this to fix with **java-1.8.0-openjdk** `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64` rather than using the asterisk so the only packages I installed with CentOS 7 at least explicitly were that one (aforementioned) and `java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64` ....

Answer (score 6):

This might also be a reason. Its simple: See if $javac works. Note: $java might work, check javac. If $javac is not working then $jps will not work either.
So you might want to do something like

> **export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin**

and try again. both javac and jps.
good luck.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the solution for the missing JPS command. I was installing Hadoop 1.x on ubuntu machine in a pseudo distributed mode. I used Java-7-openJDK to provide for the Java commands and tools. For some reason there was a **java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel**  for version 6 but none for version 7 specifically debian and ubuntu distributions. I am not sure if the same is true for Fedora and Redhat. So the best answer as that time was using the linux command

ps -aux | grep java

I hated doing that because Hadoop daemons start with so many options that each result fills up more than a screen. Apart from seeing that java is running it is impossible to see what hadoop daemons are running. Hence i came up with a short soultion in the form of one line shell script

### This is my JPS scirpt for open JDK

!#/bin/bash

ps -aux | grep java | awk '{print $12}'

### END

I saved these two lines in a file named jps and stored it in the hadoop/bin directory with execute permissions

**Here is the result of the script
hduser@localhsot# ./jps

-Dproc-namenode

-Dproc-datanode

-Dproc-JobTracker

-Dproc-TaskTracker**

Comment: Typo: !#/bin/bash should be #!/bin/bash, no?

Answer (score 2):

try this....

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to update topic for those who would face the same problem.

JDK8 also does not have the "jps" command but JDK7 does have it.

```
root@tahirpc:/home/tahir# java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (**7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1**)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

---

```
root@tahirpc:~# jps
5036 NodeManager
4368 NameNode
4912 ResourceManager
5315 Jps
4773 SecondaryNameNode
4487 DataNode
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk and not openjdk-7-jre. .

Answer (score 1):

For java 8 in ubuntu use the following command. 
 sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless

Comment: This worked for me. I had installed Java 8 on Ubuntu 17 and had faced this JPS problem but with above command I installed it and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

For Hadoop, Oracle JDK 6 [preferred](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.21.0/single_node_setup.html#Required+Software), I am not sure if someone has used OpenJDK with Hadoop successfully without any patches. FYI, there had been some talks about [support](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-general/201110.mbox/%3cCAB4CC4D.B62B%25Milind.Bhandarkar@emc.com%3e) for JDK 7 also. For now, there is too much [dependency](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-common-dev/201110.mbox/%3COF189693FF.8968F8DD-ON8725792F.005239EC-8625792F.00534E8E@us.ibm.com%3E) on Oracle JDK. Hope the dependency goes away soon.

Answer (score 0):

I found it

```
rpm -qlp java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel-1.6.0.0-1.39.1.9.7.el6.x86_64.rpm | grep jps
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/bin/jps
```

then

```
rpm -i java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel-1.6.0.0-1.39.1.9.7.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

Open syneptics package manager and install `openjdk-7-jdk` and `openjdk-6-jdk` package. AFter that jps will work

Answer (score 0):

Install `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless` not jre

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35257891)