# Hadoop: Cannot use Jps command

Tags: java, hadoop

The problem is

```
  hduser@saket-K53SM:/usr/local/hadoop$ jps
  The program 'jps' can be found in the following packages:
  * openjdk-6-jdk
  * openjdk-7-jdk
 Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

My configuration is

```
hduser@saket-K53SM:/usr/local/hadoop$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03, mixed mode)
```

set up conf/hadoop-env.sh

```
hduser@saket-K53SM:/usr/local/hadoop$ cat conf/hadoop-env.sh | grep JAVA_HOME
# The only required environment variable is JAVA_HOME.  All others are
# set JAVA_HOME in this file, so that it is correctly defined on
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_33/
```

I know there is a question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843422/hadoop-jps-can-not-find-java-installed) similar to this one.
But i have installed Sun jdk here. So any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is actually not a Hadoop problem. Hadoop does not use JPS.

If JPS can't be found, you have to put it into your path or create an alias.
The JPS executable can be found under `$JAVA_HOME/bin/jps`.

The alias for example could be:

```
alias jps='/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_33/bin/jps'
```

Or if you don't care about using JPS, you could instead do a

```
ps aux | grep java
```

which will approx. give you the same result ;)

Answer (score 9):

did you install the package **java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel** who provides the jps tool?

```
$ sudo yum provides /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/jps
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
1:java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel-1.6.0.0-1.45.1.11.1.el6.x86_64 : OpenJDK Development Environment
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Other       : Provides-match: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/jps
```

Comment: Yes, you need to do yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 to get jps ( yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 doesn't provide it)

Answer (score 8):

Use this command if you cannot use **jps**

> ps -aux | grep java | awk '{print $12}'

It will show files as:

[image: shows file like this in the picture]

Answer (score 6):

This problem is caused since you have installed JDK from Oracle (may be). You can fix this problem by using `update-alternatives` program to link `jps` to standard path directory. Use this command to fix this in a terminal

```
 sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jps jps /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6/bin/jps 1
```

Use the actual `jps` program path in the appropriate jdk (your version of jdk) instead of `jdk1.6` which is specific to me. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 4):

JPS seems (on amx linux 64 / centos at least) to be available via ant.

```
sudo yum install ant
```

and you can run jps

Answer (score 3):

on CentOS7, I fixed that problem when I installed java-devel

```
# yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using openjdk then you have install additional headless jre
try:

sudo apt-get install java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless

It worked for me,you can have to give correct openjdk version mine was 1.8

Comment: I think the op is not using openjdk, they state they are using "Sun jdk".