# Hadoop error dfs -copyFromLocal

Tags: hadoop

While moving a file in hadoop from temp directory
Used below command :-

```
[Divya@localhost hadoop]$ bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/gutenberg /home/Divya/gutenberg
```

How to resolve this error :-

```
13/07/03 14:42:28 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS) 
13/07/03 14:42:29 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS) 
13/07/03 14:42:30 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS) 
13/07/03 14:42:31 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS) 
13/07/03 14:42:32 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS) 
13/07/03 14:42:33 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS) 
13/07/03 14:42:34 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS) 
13/07/03 14:42:35 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS) 
13/07/03 14:42:36 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS) 
13/07/03 14:42:37 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS) 
copyFromLocal: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether namenode process is running on your localhost and on this port 54310

Comment: Can u please say how to check do name node Running .? Do u want me to stop and check the notification or is there any way to check it with out stopping the service

Comment: No name node is not running on my local, can help me to make this up. below are details ** [Divya@localhost hadoop]$ /home/Divya/hadoop/bin/stop-all.sh
stopping jobtracker
localhost: stopping tasktracker
no namenode to stop
localhost: stopping datanode
localhost: stopping secondarynamenode
[Divya@localhost hadoop]$ **

Comment: @user2499617 Could you please show me your NameNode logs. Looks like some problem with your configuration.

Comment: http://localhost:50070/  is not up to see the logs , is there any other way to check logs

Comment: i hope u r using linux. use jps command on the shell. check whether it returns NameNode as a process

Comment: jps in not installed in my machine , working on it, will let u know  once done, is there any other way to look at logs other than JPS command @Durairaj

Comment: @user2499617 There should be folder, named 'logs', inside your HADOOP_HOME. You can find it there.

Comment: Stack is not allowing me to post full logs, this is a piece of INFO ; ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException: Incompatible namespaceIDs in /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data: namenode namespaceID = 1300086886; datanode namespaceID = 472303482

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the hadoop daemon services are running properly. Use JPS command as root to check whether they are running properly. Make sure the cluster is properly set up.

Comment: jps in not installed in my machine , working on it, will let u know  once done, is there any other way to look at logs other than JPS command

Comment: In case it's helpful for anyone in the future, jps can be found here: 
$JAVA_HOME/bin/jps
This question discusses it in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738070/hadoop-cannot-use-jps-command