# jps command not found. Put the JDK's jps binary on the command path

Tags: hadoop, docker, java, titan

I'm trying to run a .sh file and I'm getting this following error message: "jps command not found.  Put the JDK's jps binary on the command path."

So! It seems that I need to add a path to (or alias for) jps. However, I can't find it. I looked in the path where others online said it might be (for me, /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jps) but there's no jps in the bin folder. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: There's so much info missing here. What image are you using? Where's the Dockerfile? How are you running the shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came across a similar question [hadoop jps can not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843422/hadoop-jps-can-not-find-java-installed). It mentioned that only dev version of open jdk has jps.

In your case, you may want to check the file list of your package with package list command such as:

```
rpm -ql jdk....
```

Or install oracle/sun jdk all together.

Comment: You just made me really happy. Thank you. Oracle JDK worked (with some hoop jumping, of course), I don't know why I didn't think to try it.